Is it possible to autowrap arrow labels in PlantUML?
In state diagram I have long descriptions for some transitions. I want them to be wrapped automatically. Can I do it with any style of styling now?
I tried to use
<style>
arrow {
   WordWrap 150
}
</style>

but it seems to have no effect
UPD. full example:
@startuml

skin rose

left to right direction

<style>
arrow {
     WordWrap 20
     fontcolor #green
}
</style>

state a
state b

 [*] -> a

 a -> b : very long status transition description that I want to be wrapped but it won't despite I try to use styling for arrow and it affects the arrow label font color

b -> [*]

@enduml


Which version of plantuml are you using? Can you give a small but full example of what you tried, so we can see what might be wrong.

My plantuml version is 1.2024.8
full example is
@startuml

skin rose

left to right direction

<style>
arrow {
     WordWrap 20
     fontcolor #green
}
</style>

state a
state b

 [*] -> a

 a -> b : very long status transition description that I want to be wrapped but it won't despite I try to use styling for arrow and it affects the arrow label font color

b -> [*]

@enduml


Probably not possible as in the manual at https://plantuml.com/sequence-diagram#8659eac9bf4c2629 I see that \n  are used. I think it would be a nice enhancement though.
